# How I can get GID for group in linux?

Tags: linux

I need get GID for group with name `docker`. In my case

```sh
$ cat /etc/group | grep docker
docker:x:990
```

Which command can get me `990`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

```
getent group docker | cut -d: -f3
```

to get the group id of the `docker` group.

Comment: Thank you about `cut`